# Solve nonlinear equation by taking derivatives

Tags: derivatives, nonlinear-system

I am seeking to solve a set of nonlinear equations analytically.
One of them is

1-x/y = f(z) exp(x)

Can I get further by applying derivative d/dx to both sides, which gives explicit expression for x for further use with the other equations.

x = ln(-1/(y*f(z))

Or is it nonsense to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loose Information if you derive an equation on both sides. All constants are annihilated which have essential necessity if you want to solve equations by one variable; it is not possible to use derivatives when solving equations. Therefore you must solve this equation numerically (such equations cannot be solved analytically in general), e.g. by fixed Point Iteration. You have:

$x = ln(\frac{1-\frac{x}{y}}{f(z)})$.

Then you can insert this equation on the right Hand side for x again and again.

Maybe, [this wiki article can be useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

[Numerical method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.